# Selective HTTPS to HTTP Redirect .htaccess code needed

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, ssl, https

Ok so I have an issue as a result of setting up Apple Push Notifications for safari.

on my server i have multiple sub domains, one of the sub-domains also has a SSL associated with it.

Domains:

- thechipkahouse.com (unsecured)
- tchpusher.thechipkahouse.com(secured)
- azchipka.thechipkahouse.com(unsecured)
- and so on and so forth with the sub domains all remaining are
  unsecured.

All domains live on the same IP address.

What is currently occurring is that because of the way Apple Push Notifications work when someone clicks a push notification to arrive at the site they are coming in on an https connection regardless of the domain.

So for example push notification is clicked the user should be going to thechipkahouse.com on port 80 but instead they arrive at thechipkahouse.com on port 443 via https

As a result of the url they arrive at the are being redirected to the content of tchpusher.thechipkahouse.com bush this is the domain with the ssl cert

So what I need to do is have all incoming ssl traffic redirected to non-ssl traffic unless the requested url is on the tchpusher.thechipkahouse.com subdomain. It is important though the the domain name remain intake because azchipka.thechipkahouse.com/file and thechipkahouse.com/file are two different locations.

I thought what I was looking for was this, but that didn't do it either.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^tchpush\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks for any assistance that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this rule in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of `tchpusher.thechipkahouse.com subdomain`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^tchpusher\.thechipkahouse\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```